# Alguien me podría ayudar?no importa que cantidad ponga siempre da como resultado 0

Tags: dev-c++

Es un programa que calcula el volumen de una esfera pero nose que me salio mal siempre me da como resultado 0 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Imposible ayudarte sin ver tu programa.. por favor, usa el boton [edit] y pone tu codigo en la pregunta...

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto, siempre.

Comment: El 1% de los usuarios de SO tiene algún tipo de discapacidad visual reportada. Poner una imagen con el código en medio de una gran pantalla es excluir personas del sitio. Los que vemos esto desde un móvil tampoco vemos qué hay ahí. Quienes quieran replicar tu error tendrán que transcribir a mano tu código (sí, hay gente que amablemente prueba tu código para ver cómo falla y asi tratar de darte una respuesta!). Por favor, el código se pone como texto; no tienes que transcribirlo; con copiarlo de tu IDE y pegarlo basta (ojalá poniéndole estilo código en el editor de tu pregunta)

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo revisar la sección de [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), así los usuarios podrán ayudar y entenderte de una mejor manera.

Tratándose de un código corto aquí te comparto la solución a ese problema, es de aclarar que tu código tiene varios errores que deberás ir corrigiendo con la práctica.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
    const float pi = 3.14159;
    const float numerador = 4;
    const float denominador = 3;
    float radio = 0;
    float volumen = 0;
    printf ("Por favor ingrese el radio de la esfera  ");
    scanf ("%f", & radio);
    if (radio < 0) {
        printf ("El radio de la esfera no puede ser negativo");
    }
    else {
        radio  = (pow (radio, 3));
        volumen = (( numerador * pi * radio) / denominador);
        printf ("El volumen de la esfera es igual a %.2f", volumen);
    }
    return 0;
}
```